# jvm option -Xloggc with %p in systemd.unit gives wrong log filename

Tags: systemd, java

I have a java process that I want to run with the option:

```
-Xloggc:/var/log/mylog_%p.gc.log
```

so that the name of the log file contains the PID. For example, if the process has PID 3498, the logfile name is `/var/log/mylog_pid3498.gc.log`.
I want the Java process to be initiated by a **systemd unit** file.
The unit file is:

```
[Service]
User=ubuntu
Type=simple
WorkingDirectory=/home/ubuntu/my_code
ExecStart=/usr/bin/java -Xloggc:/var/log/mylog_%%p.gc.log -jar my_code.jar
Restart=always
```

Note that I have used the `%%` character to escape the `%`. However, this does not give the expected result, since I get that the log file has name `/var/log/mylog_%p.gc.log` , i.e. Java could not do the substitution of `%p` with the actual PID.

Any idea? Thanks!

Operating system:

```
Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS (GNU/Linux 4.4.0-1066-aws x86_64)
```

Java version:

```
java version "1.8.0_181"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_181-b13)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.181-b13, mixed mode)
```

systemd version:

```
systemd 229
+PAM +AUDIT +SELINUX +IMA +APPARMOR +SMACK +SYSVINIT +UTMP +LIBCRYPTSETUP +GCRYPT +GNUTLS +ACL +XZ -LZ4 +SECCOMP +BLKID +ELFUTILS +KMOD -IDN
```

**UPDATE**

```
systemctl show -p ExecStart --no-pager my_service
ExecStart={ path=/usr/bin/java ; argv[]=/usr/bin/java -Xloggc:/var/log/mylog_%%p.gc.log -jar my_code.jar ; ignore_errors=no ; start_time=[Tue 2018-11-27 17:08:43 UTC] ; stop_time=[n/a] ; pid=1664 ; code=(null) ; status=0/0 }
```

Comment: Could not reproduce the issue here with OpenJDK 8 (the one in repositories of Ubuntu 16.04.3).
Are you sure that's what happens? Which Java runtime do you use? Please edit your question to include `systemctl show -p ExecStart <your unit>`. Also make sure you did `systemctl daemon-reload` after editing your unit.

Comment: It seems to work now, thanks @intelfx. I probably forgot to reload the daemon. Moreover, I was expecting to see the correct logfile name  (i.e. with all the substitutions) in the output of the command `ps -ef | grep java`.

Comment: As the `%p` substitution happens *inside* the `java` process, you won't see its result in there. The only exception would have been if `java` had rewritten its command line after processing it (there's no point in it, so nobody does that).